# How to login ssh server without giving password using private/public key- imported-openssh-key

Tags: shell, ssh, ssh-keys, private-key, openssh

Currently Filezilla is being used to copy from remote sever. there is require manual operation requires to copy and complete other further task after copying file. SO i need to write shell script to copy and do further task. But i facing to login server using private/public key. I have one key file which is containing following content:

```
puTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
--<Public_key>

Private-Lines: 14
---<Private_key>--

Private-MAC: --<some text>--
```

Filiezilla is successfully connecting and working properly using key .

I have already spent many hours for googling, But could not get proper solution. 
Please suggest me how do i login without password using that given key and copy file using shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution of my own question after doing research and visiting many website. PPK file contains:

```
puTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
--<Public_key>
Private-Lines: 14
---<Private_key>--

Private-MAC: --<some text>--
```

Actually we need to generate our own private key either with pass-phrase or without pass-phrase. Then we can login server using own private key.

Steps to generate private key in this [url](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/32883-how-can-i-use-private-keys-for-my-ssh-sensors-with-prtg)

https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/32883-how-can-i-use-private-keys-for-my-ssh-sensors-with-prtg

After generating private key, we can do ssh login or stp using :

```
sftp  -oIdentityFile=<generated_private_key>  <user>@<ftp_server>:<remote_directory>

ssh -i <generated_private_key>  <user>@<ftp_server>
```

we can use importance [stp_command](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/104/fall05/ordonez/sftp_cmds.shtml) for automation task: 
http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/104/fall05/ordonez/sftp_cmds.shtml

Now i can write shell script after login and listing file on Remote FTP server. if anything confusion. pls comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the private key in a file by itself on the client machine, and then:

```
ssh -i /path/to/ssh/key USER@HOSTNAME
```

Here's a tutorial: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-linuxmac/

Comment: John, thanks for the reply, i followed your way. after that the following prompt came:
`Enter passphrase for key 'private_key.txt':`

Comment: @Ramgau: That means your particular private key requires a passphrase.  If you want full automation, you need to generate a new public/private keypair which does not use a passphrase, and add that public key to the server so you can login.